# for inside for loop php not working for the two tables

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have two tables and I want to compare elements using a specific comparison with a function `compare()`. The problem is, that I have two tables: One static and one dynamic. I got first element `$results1[$i]` from the first table1 and I compare it to the first element in table2 (we suppose that table2 has one element at time 0). If the `compare()` function returns a number that is smaller than 3, I add the first element of table1 to table2, and next I have to compare the second element of table 1 with **all** elements of table2.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count ( $results1 ); $i++) {
    echo ' value 1 : ' . $results1 [$i] . '  ';
    for($k = 0; $k < count ( $results2 ); $k++) {
        echo ' value 2 : ' . $results2 [$k] . '  ';
        compare($results1 [$i],$results2 [$k]);
    }   
}

function compare($element1_table1,$element2_table2){
    if ($results_of_comparison< 3){
        //we add element1 to table2 and 
       //then we compare the next element of table 1 with all elements of table2
    }
}
```

How to compare the next element of table 1 with all elements of table2 using the loop?
Can someone help me please?

Comment: If result < 3 … What needs to be the result of the comparison of the next element of table1 with all elements of table2 ?

Comment: if the results of comparison is < 3 we add the element of table1 to table 2, and next we compare the next element of table 1 with all elements of table2, if the results is <3 we add this element of table1 to table2. And then again we compare the next element of table1 to the 3 elements in table2

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays have the same structure you can use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to output those entries that are only contained in the first of the two arrays

```
$results1   = array(1,2,3,4);
$results2   = array(1,2,5);

$difference = array_diff($results1, $results2);
```

This will return

```
3, 4
```

OR

If the arrays have the same structure you can use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to output those entries that are contained in both of the two arrays

```
$results1   = array(1,2,3,4);
$results2   = array(1,2,5);

$difference = array_intersect($results1, $results2);
```

This will return

```
1, 2
```

Example:

```
$static  = array(1, 4, 6, 9);
$dynamic = array();

foreach($anything as $value){
  $dynamic[] = $value;
}

$difference = array_intersect($static, $dynamic);
```

Comment: Yes but I already have my function and it worked, I have a problem with the loop when I add an element to results2, I have to compare the element1 of results1 to all elements of table2

Comment: i edited my posting. you can also return those elements that are contained in both arrays. with these two functions you can easily compare your arrays.

Comment: Yes I already used those functions inside my specific function, my problem is how I can use the loop for to compare all elements of table1 with elements of the dynamic table2?

Comment: there is no need to compare it within the loop. the first Array is static you said. just generate the second in your loop (if needed) and if you have both arrays ready compare them at the end.

Comment: i posted an example